# Selenium Test Automation Issue: Unable to Verify Price Range Sorting in Shopping Cart (Problem in reloading same page)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, url, automation

I'm doing a test automation project using selenium and this is my first time using it. Here I have to capture this bug. "When I click a link to sort a shopping cart by price range it does not load the relevant page instead reload the current page" . this is my Test.

```
   @Test(priority = 2 , groups = {"smoke"})
    public void verifyFilterByPrice(){
        ProductDetailPage productdetailpage = new ProductDetailPage(driver);
        productdetailpage.NavigateToItemDescriptionPage();
        String urlBefore = productdetailpage.getCurrentPageUrl();
        productdetailpage.clickPriceRange();
        String urlAfter = productdetailpage.getCurrentPageUrl();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(urlBefore, urlAfter, "Page URL didn't change after clicking Price Range.");

    }
```

and these are the methods used in the code.

```
 public String getCurrentPageUrl(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        String currentPageUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("the curent url you capture is " + currentPageUrl);
        return currentPageUrl;

    }
```

but when I log both urls they are like  follow. and they are not same to I cant assert as equal. Is ther is another way I could use to assert such senarios?

```
URL befor = https://xxxx/s/zzz/
URL after = is https://xxxx/s/zzz/?perpage=25&pricepoint=2
```

Comment: What is the expected URL? Why can't you just assert vs that? Also, please post the contents of the method `.NavigateToItemDescriptionPage()`? You really should be handling the URL transition in that method instead of `.getCurrentPageUrl()`.

Answer (score 1):

For a web page, a title is a unique thing. If you navigate to a different page then the previous and current web page titles should be different.

Method inside Sort Class:

```
 public boolean sortItems() {
       String currentWebPageTitle= driver.getTitle();
       By priceSortOption = By.cssSelector("add your locator here");

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(priceSortOption));
       driver.findElement(priceSortOption).click();
       String webPageTitleAfterSorting = driver.getTitle();
       boolean isReloaded = currentWebPageTitle.equals(webPageTitleAfterSorting);
       return isReloaded;
    }
```

TestCase:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void sortItemsTest(){
        StorePage storePage=new StorePage(driver);
        Assert.assertFalse(storePage.sortItems(), "Sorting by price resulted in a page reload.");
    }
```